# retrieving datatbase information on a web page

Tags: php, html

This will be a total novices question, but I am looking for advice.

My apologies, In the post as I failed to mention that the database that I am working on is MySQL.

I know absolutely nothing in regards to any technologies that retrieve or get information from a database. The only 3 facts that I know is that it can be done by either PHP or HTML5, I should be able to pick it up and that I will make many mistakes

Could the community suggest which would be the better technology to learn and would any be able to suggest a starting point?

Yours in advance

Keith

Comment: Sorry, we don't recommend tutorials here

Comment: In the only 3 facts that you know, the database type is missing (mysql ? sqlserver ? Oracle ?)
However you will have to deal with PHP. A simple google search will give you plenty clues to start

Comment: I was just about to post an answer to this as well until the mods closed the question -__-.. here is my answer I figured it's worth trying to help either way. http://pastebin.com/P5VE3b6k

Answer (score 2):

In order to retrieve database information, you generally only need a database such as MySQL - and a client to perform your queries (fetching data from the database).

Your client could be anything, a commandline tool or a PHP script opening a connection to your database and performing the desired queries.

Fetching data alone will not get you very far unless you can display that information somewhere, or even provide access to it or (if desired) allow users to interact with it.

Basically, if you want to retrieve database information and show it on a website, your minimum requirements would be HTML, a database server, a database (preferably with some data to run some tests with) and some kind of scripting language (such as PHP).

There are numerous tutorials out there on how to make your first steps with this.

[Here is one.](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_and_mysql_tutorial_-_lesson_1/)

Comment: Don't suggested old posts with deprecated methods such as mysql_*, nonetheless, upvoted, it was a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with PHP + MySQL. There are a lot of manuals and examples over the Internet. Google it.